# Generic method syntax clarification

Tags: c#, generics

1)When I have

```
Static void Sample<T>(T a,T b)
```

Does the declaration Sample enforce that all parameters need to be of type T ?

2) Does the declaration `Static void Sample(T a,T b)` not a Generic method unless i specify 
  `Sample<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. indeed, in your example, both parameters are of type T therefore need to ..um.. be of type T. You could of course declare a method that uses different types.

   static void Sample<T>(T a,SomeType b)
2. Yes, it is not generic unless you specify Sample**<T>**(T a,T b)

Answer (score 5):

1) No, `Static void Sample<T>(T a,T b)` does not enforce all parameters to be of type T. You can have other parameters in method arguments also. EDIT:- You can have Sample(T a, int b, string s) (if this is what you mean)

2) Yes, `Static void Sample(T a,T b)` is non-generic and compiler will throw exception about type T (if you don't have a classed named T)

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes

2) Yes, this is invalid syntax for a generic method

EDIT: More almost instantaneous answering :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the declaration enforces that all of the declared parameters need to be of type T.
2. `static void Sample(T a, T b)` will fail to compile (unless you have a type T) because it is not a generic declaration. You need the  for the declaration to be a generic.